# How do you save TextBox, comboBox, CheckBox inputs to ListView in WPF (C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listview, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a Valet Parking WPF application. I just want to know how you save user inputs to ListView and how to do remove stored data in ListView.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You are not supposed to use visual controls as a storage.

Comment: How do you save user inputs then?

Comment: That depends, if you don't need to permanently store the inputs you can just create a class to hold the various fields. If you need to permanently store them then you should still create the class but save it to a database or file on the hard drive etc, XML is a good option for smaller apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats up to your wish; You can store in a file or even a database, then show in the GridView within a  ListView;

```
public class CarInfo
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then we need to parse the text file:

```
List<ProcessInfo> processes = new List<ProcessInfo>();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt');
reader.ReadLine(); //The headers don't matter!

string currentLine;
while (currentLine = reader.ReadLine() != null)
{
    ProcessInfo newInfo = new ProcessInfo();
    // String separation can be done if needed; Can use String.Split API
    processes.Add(newInfo);
}
```

Finally, we need to set up the XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Processes}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Hi Javi, Does this helped you to find a solution?